Always allow duplicate-voting in Re-Evaluate, regardless of previous states
Motivation
Finding a duplicate of a question and marking it as such might be the best action that can be done in the Staging Ground. As many questions on Stack Overflow were asked before, many questions in the Staging Ground can be marked as such. If the author makes clarifications to their question, they can "Re-Evaluate" it and there may be a different appropriate review action in which case it can be amended easier than on the main site. Or there may be another duplicate which the Staging Ground doesn't really have any option for except writing a comment with the new question and using the "Decline Re-Evaluation" option (which isn't really made for that purpose).
Similarly, it might happen that a question is closed for some reason, the author clarifies a few things, Re-Evaluates and a reviewer finds a duplicate. Since the question is in the "Re-Evaluate" state but still closed, neither the off-topic nor the duplicate option can be used/there's no way of moving a question from off-topic to duplicate.
I also think that it's better to look for duplicates early, even when there's a risk of misunderstanding the question. In the worst case, the OP just Re-Evaluates it and you can help them clarify the difference. Being wrong on a duplicate shouldn't make subsequent reviews harder.
My suggestion
I want to suggest giving reviewers the ability to use the "Vote as duplicate" option whenever the question is in the Re-Evaluate state, even in the following cases:

The question has been re-evaluated in the off-topic or duplicate state
The same reviewer has previously voted to mark the question as duplicate/off-topic

This would allow questions to be moved from off-topic to duplicate, changing the duplicate target or use the duplicate option when a question was a duplicate (or off-topic) before but then changed to "Requires Major Changes".
While this isn't an issue for most cases, there not being any good options for some questions can be quite annoying and I think looking for duplicates should be incentivized rather than made more difficult.
This is similar to another feature request I wrote during the beta (beta-testers only link) which was only about changing the duplicate target. This suggestion was declined as too much of an edge-case during the beta but I am now reposting a more general feature request to see whether this is needed (are there any other reviewers who ran into this problem?) and maybe getting something in that direction going.
What I am not suggesting
I am not saying that it should be possible to freely move questions between duplicate and off-topic as I don't really see much use in that.
This proposal focuses on the duplicate option and isn't really about of-topic as I think the "Decline Re-Evaluation" option is good enough for that and other reviewers can be vote for the question to be off-topic in the case of Off-topic-->Re-Evaluate-->Major Changes-->Off-topic.
I am also not suggesting to only require a single reviewer for these actions. In my suggestion, the requirement of having two reviewers (or one gold-badger) to mark a question as a duplicate would not be affected.
I don't have strong opinions on the things I'm not suggesting, these things can be discussed as well.

Is there any reason this should be limited to the SG? Why not allow duplicate closure votes pretty much always for all questions? (Fairly certain this broader request already exists in one form or the other, though I didn't find it)

I am not opposed to doing this in general but I think that would need more discussion and is overall harder (riskier?) to do so I think it makes sense to limit the scope (for now at least). The issue with the Staging Ground comes from not being the duplicate option in the Re-Evaluate state in certain cases.
